# ¿El comando"trans" no me traduce italiano a español?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -ne "Ingrese un texto: "; read txt

echo "---El resultado es: " $(trans -b :es "$txt")
```

el problema que tengo es que cuando quiero traducir palabras cortas" Ciao viene ser Hola "de italiano a español ---> :"Ciao" me sigue traduciendo el mismo idioma italiano

Comment: Bienvenido Deriams a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: No necesitas copiar el Script completo, de hecho es contraproducente para tu pregunta. Básicamente el comando por el cual estas preguntando es algo como esto: `txt="Buenas noches a todos";echo "---El resultado es: " $(trans -b :it "$txt")` que por cierto acabo de probar y funciona. ¿Que error tienes?¿Que resultado obtienes? ¿Que texto intentas traducir?

Comment: Esta bien. Pero el problema que tengo es que cuando quiero  traducir palabras  cortas" Ciao viene ser Hola "de italiano a español ---> :"Ciao" me sigue traduciendo el mismo idioma italiano "txt="Ciao";echo "---El resultado es: " $(trans -b :es "$txt")

Comment: Acabo de chequear esto: `txt="Ciao";echo "---El resultado es: " $(trans -b :es "$txt")` y la salida es: `---El resultado es:  ¡Hola`

Comment: Sigo teniendo el mismo problema; cuándo aumentó una palabra más, me la traduce normalmente txt="Ciao mondo";echo "---El resultado es: " $(trans -b :es "$txt") y su salida es: --- El Resultado es: Hola mundo.          y cuando pongo tan solo palabra corta txt="Ciao";echo "---El resultado es: " $(trans -b :es "$txt")  y su salida es: --- El Resultado es: Chao. Me la traduce en Inglés

Comment: No logro reproducir tu problema, copie tu código en un script y pruebo ingresar `Ciao Mondo`  y me retorna `---El resultado es:  Hola mundo`

Comment: En el caso de una palabra cortas no me llega a traducir como debe de ser.   txt="Ciao";echo "---El resultado es: " $(trans -b :es "$txt")---El resultado es: Chao  <------ Ami me lo traduce  en Inglés y no en español

Comment: No sé que decirte, lamentablemente no puedo reproducir lo que dices, si te sirve el dato, estoy probando con la version 0.9.6. de trans.

Comment: Cuando quiero traducir de " italiano  a  español " en palabras cortas como por ejemplo: Ciao y me retorna --- el resultado es : Chao , Osea me la traduce  en Inglés.  y cuando lo aumentó una palabra más y lo tradusco : "Ciao mondo"  me traduce Bien : Hola mundo , uso Termux y el paquete apt install translate-shell

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo; acabo de resolver el problema que tenía era de estas manera: it:es y de igualmente  muchísimas gracias amigo , por favor me podrás dejar tu correo plis